# After retrieving list should be available to other methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the code..I have used the Session to achieve this but the page is taking long time to load.I was wondering is there any better way to achieve this..

```
protected void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

List<Employee> empobj=empdal.getlist();
Session["emp"]=empobj;
}
```

I want the empobj list to be available for below method

```
private void download()
{
List<Employee> empstorelist=Session["emp"] as  List<Employee>;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're storing a huge load on that list, I don't think your webapp slowness is related to Session write/read.
You'll need to narrow down further.

Answer (score 0):

What mode of session are you using? InProc is faster than StateServer mode and SqlServer mode I think, however i would imagine sqlserver mode can handle large amounts of data stored in session better than InProc if you have lots of sessions storing lots of data.

You could always serialise it to JSON and store in a hiddenfield then desterilise it when you need to use it. I'm not sure that's any better though. just a thought.

Comment: Inproc with serialize  .. About the data is 700-800 rows of query information which might increase as data is daily updated